# Extract the a value from this line

Tags: python, python-2.6

i know this has been asked many times before but I am struggling to extract the middle of the bellow line

```
id1=({'children': '', 'edgeParameter': 1.0, 'id': 8, 'isOutOfDate': False, 'name': 'Datum pt-5', 'parents': '1&', 'path': 'unknown', 'sketch': 'unknown'})
```

The result I am trying to get is the id number. In this case 8.

```
output= 8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean by *middle of string* and  what have you tried?

Comment: id1[id1.find("'id':")+1:id1.find(',')]

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: Dictionaries don't function the same as lists

Comment: The dictionaries are unordered lists. So there is no *middle* for a dictionary

Comment: ... and what is ``id1`` in your reply here? That's not in the question. To be clear, the location has no meaning in a dictionary if that is what you mean by "middle". Just use indexing, ``myDict['id']``. Also, why the parenthesis around the dictionary?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and explain what you wish to accomplish with example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: sorry I'm not the best at writing code. but the line is an output from a cae package and I need to use the id number for the rest of my code

Comment: @manish449 What is the output of running ``type(id1)``?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parenthesis around the dictionary does nothing when it's not explicitly turned into a tuple. Try e.g. comparing `print type((1))` to print `print type((1, ))`. Then just use dictionary indexing. `print id1['id']`. This is really the most basic python so if this is caused you problems, do a basic python course, e.g. on coursera.

If what you posted is literally a python `str` and it always contains parenthesis with a single dictionary representation within it, containing the key 'id', then a very simple approach is to slice the string around the corresponding value of 'id.

```py
id1 = "({'children': '', 'edgeParameter': 1.0, 'id': 8, 'isOutOfDate': False, 'name': 'Datum pt-5', 'parents': '1&', 'path': 'unknown', 'sketch': 'unknown'})"
output = id1.split("'id':")[1].split(',')[0]
```

This is itself a string including any prefix or trailing spaces. If you know this to always be an integer, do `output = int(output)`. To break it down:

```py
id1.split("'id':")  # creates a list with two elements: everything up until 'id' and everything after it
id1.split("'id':")[1]  # selects everything after 'id', the first thing being the desired value
id1.split("'id':")[1].split(',')  # breaks THAT string up where there are commas since the value ends with a comma.
id1.split("'id':")[1].split(',')[0]  # selects the value
```

One could also use `eval` instead of the approach above but that's always discouraged!